Is 好きじゃねえな人 correct?
would 好きじゃねえな人 be grammatically correct for "people I don't like"? or does it have to be 嫌いな人?

好きじゃねえ人 without な works (this is not a な adjective) but is somewhat crude compared to 好きじゃない人
あい to ええ is a somewhat common sound change but it's associated with men speaking in very informal settings

thank you, can you elaborate on why its crude?

@towa Because the ～あい → ～ええ change for い adjectives is a very informal of speaking. You should never speak like this in situations where you need to convey politeness or seriousness.

I know this question was already answered but I was hoping to clarify some assumptions made in this example sentence to better explain why they are wrong.
Firstly, じゃねえ is a hypercasual form of ではない. This, in turn, is the negative phrase to である which literally means "to exist as...". This is the origin of the copula だ, which has the same meaning, but is used and translated the way we say "Is (something)".
I explain all this to now tell you that な, the particle that attaches adjectives to nouns, comes from the similar phrase にある meaning "To exist being...".
Both だ and な connect to adjectives the same way, and are considered by many to be the same phrase in different contexts; だ concludes phrases with na-adjectives, すきだ "it is liked"; while な joins the phrase to a noun, 好きな人 "a person who is liked".
The second thing I'll point out is that ない is an i-adjective. All i-adjectives inherently mean "To be" already. In this case ない means "To be nonexistent". Using だ or な is redundant after i-adjectives because it results in the phrasing;
ないだ "it is being that it is nonexistent".
People jump to the extreme conclusion that 'i-adjectives + だ' are ungrammatical, but that's not true either. It is grammatically correct, but never used because it sounds repetitive. This is proven by the fact that the polite form of だ, です, IS used after i-adjectives, as a tool to make them polite.
So, you do not need to connect 好きじゃねぇ to 人 using な. 好きじゃねぇな人 would sound like "a person who is being that which is not liked."

I understand what you're trying to add here, but it's really just being pedantic about details that aren't relevant to answering the question - and then getting those details mostly wrong. です being used after i-adjectives is a special case, resulting from them not having a more obvious polite form; and it wasn't always considered grammatical. i-adjective + だ is considered simply ungrammatical - の (or ん) is required as a linker, and then adding on to the i-adjective changes the meaning somewhat. And on the flip side of that, です is not used in relative clauses.

I suppose one could correctly say 好きじゃないにある人, if you were trying to make that point (and also explain that it's pointlessly wordy).

It sounds like something chat gpt would write...

I suppose I understand your confusion if we're looking at this from a prescriptivist point of view. When I say ungrammatical, I mean sentence structures that are syntactically and meaningfully invalid. I did not say that じゃないだ is grammatical and therefore correct. It's grammatical syntactically but morphologically redundant. の and です appear after i-adjectives because that structure is a syntactically valid phrase, and they introduce additional meaning. だ does not add meaning. It is not because some rule prevents you from putting them after i-adjectives.  That's not how communication works.

It is true that な and だ developed as phonological contractions of にある and である, but your translations of these にある and である as "to exist being..." and "to exist as..." are wrong. Both にある and である simply mean "am/art/is/are". Besides 似{に} (Continuative form of 似{に}る), 二{に} etc., it makes sense to consider that Japanese language has 2 に and 2 で: 1. に and で which are forms of verb n-; 2. に and で particles (at least で particle developed from aforementioned で form of verb n-, it is possible that に particle also developed from aforementioned に form of verb n-).

Verb n- is defective and is missing several forms, which would be needed sometimes, so Japanese language developed periphrastic constructions to express desired meanings. These periphrastic constructions consist of forms of 2 verbs: ni (Continuative of verb n-) or nite / de (Conjunctive/Gerund of verb n-; de is contraction of nite) + some other verb used for conjugation. That second verb is often ar-, but throughout history of Japanese language some other verbs have seen use, in modern times mostly verb gozar-.

These periphrastic constructions are syntactically similar to compound verbs. In both cases, the first verb remains in the same form, while the second verb is conjugated for appropriate tense, aspect, voice etc. Semantically, in ni aru, ni imasu, de aru, de gozaru, de saurau → de sɔːrɔː etc. constructions, verbal form ni or de gives meaning "to be" to whole construction, and meaning of the second verb is ignored. Verb ar- is similarly used for forming some forms of adjectives (e.g. past tense: yoku aritaru → yokatta) and now-archaic negative suffix -an-.

There is also a different ni aru / de aru, homophonic to ni aru / de aru discussed above, but grammatically very different, and consisting of case particle ni or de + lexical verb aru "to exist, to happen, to occur": noun denoting place + ni + aru ("to exist in some place"); noun denoting place + de + aru ("to happen, to occur in some place").
